# How do you make a timer that counts up with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, timer

How do I make a timer with jQuery that counts up with out plugins or anything like that? I have looked around on multiple sites but I haven't found anything that works. Everything I've found counts down or doesn't work for me. I'm using jQuery 2.1.4.

Comment: Can you also include in your post what you have tried, searched and, researched so far?
[ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[tour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
We can better assist you if you can narrow down the problem or share with us a reproducible example.
[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I am following exactly and you didn't mention your use case, but I think you may find this useful:

```
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Just replace the alert with your code and it will be run every 3 second. So to make a counter just do  I=I+1 inside there.

Do you need to display the I in html? Then

```
 $("#yourID").append(I)
```